# How to give fixed percentage value of column width in iText JAVA

Tags: java, pdf, itext7, fixed-width, column-width

Here I am using **iText 7** for generations of pdf. I have set table width 100% using
`table.setWidthPercent(100)` and i want fixed column width which is in percentage.

I set column width like below

```
 float columnWidth[] = {33,34,33};
 Table table = new Table(columnWidth);
```

but it's not percentage when we execute it will gives 3 column with this relative width but this one is break when we give left margin to last cell.

**Every Cell left,right margin is affecting column width I want fixed size of column in percentage**

Here is my whole code and output image.

```
        String pdfPath = "first.pdf";
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(pdfPath);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);
        pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
        document.setMargins(20,20,20,20);

        float columnWidth[] = {33,34,33};
        Table table = new Table(columnWidth);
        table.setWidthPercent(100);
        table.addCell(new Cell().add("First").setFontSize(7).setMargins(0,0,0,0));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add("Second").setFontSize(7).setMargins(0,0,0,0));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add("Third").setFontSize(7).setMargins(0,0,0,50));
        document.add(table);
        document.close();
        System.out.println("pdf created");
```

This one is output of above code:

[image: This one is output of above code]

**Want fixed column size even if apply left margin. it should affect only on text not on column Here column size is changing**

Want this type of behaviour:

[image: Want this type of behaviour]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving float value directly

```
  float columnWidth[] = {33,34,33};
  Table table = new Table(columnWidth);
```

UnitValue solved my query

```
 Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(columnWidth));
```

Now Column width is fixed. Cell margin won't affect column width.